# Apache Mesos - Docker container

Tags: docker, mesos

I am trying to run mesos using a docker container.

I pulled the docker image from

https://github.com/mesosphere/docker-containers/tree/master/mesos

I tried running the docker using the below command,

docker run mesosphere/mesos-master:1.0.3-rc2 --quorum=1 --zk=zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos --work_dir=/tmp/

docker logs,

```
I0208 08:34:15.901656     6 main.cpp:237] Build: 2016-04-14 15:43:08 by root
I0208 08:34:15.904043     6 main.cpp:239] Version: 0.28.1
I0208 08:34:15.904062     6 main.cpp:242] Git tag: 0.28.1
I0208 08:34:15.904067     6 main.cpp:246] Git SHA: 555db235a34afbb9fb49940376cc33a66f1f85f0
I0208 08:34:15.904125     6 main.cpp:260] Using 'HierarchicalDRF' allocator
I0208 08:34:15.966691     6 leveldb.cpp:174] Opened db in 62.418286ms
I0208 08:34:15.971434     6 leveldb.cpp:181] Compacted db in 4.673451ms
I0208 08:34:15.971494     6 leveldb.cpp:196] Created db iterator in 11586ns
I0208 08:34:15.971525     6 leveldb.cpp:202] Seeked to beginning of db in 6392ns
I0208 08:34:15.971557     6 leveldb.cpp:271] Iterated through 0 keys in the db in 22873ns
I0208 08:34:15.971614     6 replica.cpp:779] Replica recovered with log positions 0 -> 0 with 1 holes and 0 unlearned
I0208 08:34:15.972483     6 main.cpp:471] Starting Mesos master
I0208 08:34:15.972503     8 recover.cpp:447] Starting replica recovery
I0208 08:34:15.972690    10 recover.cpp:473] Replica is in EMPTY status
I0208 08:34:15.973593    10 replica.cpp:673] Replica in EMPTY status received a broadcasted recover request from (4)@172.17.0.3:5050
I0208 08:34:15.973703    10 recover.cpp:193] Received a recover response from a replica in EMPTY status
I0208 08:34:15.973799    10 recover.cpp:564] Updating replica status to STARTING
I0208 08:34:15.974968     6 master.cpp:375] Master 0f1b52f6-cda9-4017-880f-ab3358875dbb (ea467d55e3fb) started on 172.17.0.3:5050
I0208 08:34:15.975086     6 master.cpp:377] Flags at startup: --allocation_interval="1secs" --allocator="HierarchicalDRF" --authenticate="false" --authenticate_http="false" --authenticate_slaves="false" --authenticators="crammd5" --authorizers="local" --framework_sorter="drf" --help="false" --hostname_lookup="true" --http_authenticators="basic" --initialize_driver_logging="true" --log_auto_initialize="true" --logbufsecs="0" --logging_level="INFO" --max_completed_frameworks="50" --max_completed_tasks_per_framework="1000" --max_slave_ping_timeouts="5" --port="5050" --quiet="false" --recovery_slave_removal_limit="100%" --registry="replicated_log" --registry_fetch_timeout="1mins" --registry_store_timeout="20secs" --registry_strict="false" --root_submissions="true" --slave_ping_timeout="15secs" --slave_reregister_timeout="10mins" --user_sorter="drf" --version="false" --webui_dir="/usr/share/mesos/webui" --work_dir="/tmp/mesos" --zk_session_timeout="10secs"
I0208 08:34:15.975765     6 master.cpp:424] Master allowing unauthenticated frameworks to register
I0208 08:34:15.976063     6 master.cpp:429] Master allowing unauthenticated slaves to register
I0208 08:34:15.976227     6 master.cpp:467] Using default 'crammd5' authenticator
I0208 08:34:15.976296    10 leveldb.cpp:304] Persisting metadata (8 bytes) to leveldb took 2.432612ms
I0208 08:34:15.976330    10 replica.cpp:320] Persisted replica status to STARTING
I0208 08:34:15.976387    10 recover.cpp:473] Replica is in STARTING status
W0208 08:34:15.976258     6 authenticator.cpp:511] No credentials provided, authentication requests will be refused
I0208 08:34:15.976528     6 authenticator.cpp:518] Initializing server SASL
I0208 08:34:15.976541    10 replica.cpp:673] Replica in STARTING status received a broadcasted recover request from (5)@172.17.0.3:5050
I0208 08:34:15.976599    10 recover.cpp:193] Received a recover response from a replica in STARTING status
I0208 08:34:15.976668    10 recover.cpp:564] Updating replica status to VOTING
I0208 08:34:15.977293    10 leveldb.cpp:304] Persisting metadata (8 bytes) to leveldb took 581510ns
I0208 08:34:15.977344    10 replica.cpp:320] Persisted replica status to VOTING
I0208 08:34:15.977378    10 recover.cpp:578] Successfully joined the Paxos group
I0208 08:34:15.977409    10 recover.cpp:462] Recover process terminated
I0208 08:34:15.982031     9 master.cpp:1711] The newly elected leader is master@172.17.0.3:5050 with id 0f1b52f6-cda9-4017-880f-ab3358875dbb
I0208 08:34:15.982081     9 master.cpp:1724] Elected as the leading master!
I0208 08:34:15.982089     9 master.cpp:1469] Recovering from registrar
I0208 08:34:15.982128     9 registrar.cpp:307] Recovering registrar
I0208 08:34:15.982303     9 log.cpp:659] Attempting to start the writer
I0208 08:34:15.982481     9 replica.cpp:493] Replica received implicit promise request from (6)@172.17.0.3:5050 with proposal 1
I0208 08:34:15.983101     9 leveldb.cpp:304] Persisting metadata (8 bytes) to leveldb took 515088ns
I0208 08:34:15.983155     9 replica.cpp:342] Persisted promised to 1
I0208 08:34:15.983306     9 coordinator.cpp:238] Coordinator attempting to fill missing positions
I0208 08:34:15.983456     9 replica.cpp:388] Replica received explicit promise request from (7)@172.17.0.3:5050 for position 0 with proposal 2
I0208 08:34:15.985903     9 leveldb.cpp:341] Persisting action (8 bytes) to leveldb took 2.407242ms
I0208 08:34:15.985947     9 replica.cpp:712] Persisted action at 0
I0208 08:34:15.986131     9 replica.cpp:537] Replica received write request for position 0 from (8)@172.17.0.3:5050
I0208 08:34:15.986181     9 leveldb.cpp:436] Reading position from leveldb took 18078ns
I0208 08:34:15.986785     9 leveldb.cpp:341] Persisting action (14 bytes) to leveldb took 568426ns
I0208 08:34:15.986866     9 replica.cpp:712] Persisted action at 0
I0208 08:34:15.986990     9 replica.cpp:691] Replica received learned notice for position 0 from @0.0.0.0:0
```

Still, I am unable to connect to the mesos GUI using http://localhost:5050.

Am i missing anything here.

Thanks

Comment: Did you run it with `--net=host`? Apparently no as your logs show Docker's "internal" ip `172.17.0.3`. ref. [networking](https://github.com/mesosphere/docker-containers/tree/master/mesos#networking)

Comment: I am getting the below error when i run with --net=host

WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0210 15:48:42.993381     1 main.cpp:263] Build: 2017-01-31 19:49:52 by ubuntu
I0210 15:48:42.994377     1 main.cpp:264] Version: 1.0.3
I0210 15:48:42.994390     1 main.cpp:267] Git tag: 1.0.3-rc2
I0210 15:48:42.994395     1 main.cpp:271] Git SHA: c673fdd00e7f93ab7844965435d57fd691fb4d8d
Failed to obtain the IP address for 'moby'; the DNS service may not be able to resolve it: Name or service not known

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
curl 172.17.0.3:5050
```

from command line, and you should get response from Mesos GUI.

You can get more info about docker networking here

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/binding/
http://www.dasblinkenlichten.com/docker-networking-101-host-mode/

Also, your firewall could block your connections.

Comment: curl 172.17.0.3:5050  - hangs for ever.  I tired http://172.17.0.3:5050 and it keeps loading .....

Comment: can you login to docker and check mesos logs and mesos-master status?

You can login like this
(https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/exec)
 see this: `docker exec -it DOCKERID bash` .  DOCKERID can be found if you type `docker ps`.

Comment: I am able to login. 
mesos-master status
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
I0210 15:45:17.019531    78 main.cpp:263] Build: 2017-01-31 19:49:52 by ubuntu
I0210 15:45:17.019656    78 main.cpp:264] Version: 1.0.3
I0210 15:45:17.019665    78 main.cpp:267] Git tag: 1.0.3-rc2
I0210 15:45:17.019671    78 main.cpp:271] Git SHA: c673fdd00e7f93ab7844965435d57fd691fb4d8d
F0210 15:45:17.020546    78 process.cpp:944] Failed to initialize: Failed to bind on 0.0.0.0:5050: Address already in use: Address already in use [98]
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Aborted

Comment: This means that mesos-master can not run since something is using port 5050. You were using rc2 version of docker. They published new one, https://hub.docker.com/r/mesosphere/mesos-master/tags/ try 1.0.3